# Debug python Visual Studio Startup very slow - load module

Tags: python, visual-studio

When start debug from Visual Studio, it takes like 2 minutes to hit the first line of python code. Apparently Visual Studio is busy loading python modules.

python.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'python.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'xxxxx'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
... many more ...

I tried below, no joy:

1. Tools \ Options \ Debugging

   a) Enable Just My Code checked

   b) Just-In-Time Debugging - only selected Managed and Script

   c) Symbols

   - unchecked "Microsoft Symbol Servers"
   - "Load all modules, unless excluded" or "Load only specified modules" (tried both)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/

2. Reinstall Visual Studio (I tried both Community Edition, Standard Edition)
3. Reboot my machine three times
4. Delete all breakpoints
5. Disable Resharper

Two more observations:

1. I never had this issue prior to today
2. Python Interactive Debugger stopped working today - it refuse to print anything!

   myDataFrame.head()

   print("hello")

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!!
I deleted my Visual Studio solution and project file. Create the python project brand new, all fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is looking around,

I also had horrendous debug times (2+ minutes to get to the first line of code).

I was using an Anaconda deployment for numpy/scipy along with pybind11 to interface/debug C code.

I fixed my debug times by using a vanilla deployment of python (3.9.1) and installing the minimal requirements using pip.  I believe it was taking so long because visual studio is searching for debug symbols that do not exist.  **Anaconda does not provide symbol libraries** (nor will they according to their forums)

Debug times are now as fast as normal run times (<1s) and I'm no longer dreading hitting the little bug button.

Answer (score 0):

To disable "Enable native code debugging" in the solution properties helped for me.